# automatic computaion

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then Exit Sub
TextBox3.Text = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

This code works for me but when i delete both value of the textbox the total is still there... any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have no code to remove the value from the output TextBox (TextBox3) when the input TextBoxes (TextBox1 and TextBox2) are cleared. You could just clear TextBox3 at the start of the TextChanged event handler.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then Exit Sub
    TextBox3.Text = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + CDbl(TextBox2.Text)).ToString
End Sub
```